# expansion of variables in callbacks node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following piece of code which should implement three callback functions for three port configurations of a TCP server. The console output should report for which of the three channels it is set up but it does not presumably because the expansion of variable "i" is done at run time of the callback and therefore gets the last value of i which is 2.
My question: How can I make node expand my variable "i" when the callback is defined?

Thanks for helping in advance.

---

```
var p_arr = [   
    {src_port: 5500, src_host: "localhost", dst_port: 5501, dst_host: "localhost"},
    {src_port: 5502, src_host: "localhost", dst_port: 5503, dst_host: "localhost"},
    {src_port: 5504, src_host: "localhost", dst_port: 5505, dst_host: "localhost"},
];

for (var i in p_arr) {
    try {
        rcv_soc[i] = net.createServer(function (stream) {
            if (verbose & 1) console.log("Listening on host %s, port %s...", p_arr[i].src_host, p_arr[i].src_port);
            stream.on("data", function (data) {
                if (verbose & 4) console.log("Received from app %d: %s", i, data);
            });
        });

        rcv_soc[i].listen(p_arr[i].src_port, p_arr[i].src_host);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("No connection possible !!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap that in a self-executing func with `i` as the param:

```
for (var i in p_arr) (function(i) {
try {
    rcv_soc[i] = net.createServer(function (stream) {
        if (verbose & 1) console.log("Listening on host %s, port %s...", p_arr[i].src_host, p_arr[i].src_port);
        stream.on("data", function (data) {
            if (verbose & 4) console.log("Received from app %d: %s", i, data);
        });
    });

    rcv_soc[i].listen(p_arr[i].src_port, p_arr[i].src_host);
}
catch (err) {
    console.log("No connection possible !!");
}
})(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to scoping rules in Javascript.

The simplest solution is to use `forEach` to create a new (function) scope for each item in the array:

```
p_arr.forEach(function(entry, i) {
  // 'entry' is the same as 'p_arr[i]'
  ...
});
```